# Unity Generic List in Hierarchy

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, generics

I'm looking to have an undoclass, which has all of the undo moves for all objects on the board.

Setup:

```
public class UndoClass
{
    public UndoLogging[] _Discs;
    public TileParent[] _Tiles;

    public UndoClass(UndoLogging[] discs, TileParent[] tiles)
    {
        _Discs = discs;
        _Tiles = tiles;
    }
}

class AddToList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        list.Add(t);
    }
}
```

TileParent is a parent script, and a bunch of different tiles are under that, and so each of those tiles would need a different Undo List with variables that need undoing.

How would I create the generic list in TileParent but use a specific type for the list inside the individual tiles?

```
public class TileParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AddToList<T> _UndoLog = new AddToList<T>();
}

public class BreakableTile : TileParent
{
    struct MyLog
    {
        bool active;
    }

    public override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();

        _UndoLog = new List<MyLog>();
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

The error the above code generates is

```
TileParent.cs(12,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly clear what you have problem with... Does version of the code you've posted (with syntax errors fixed up) cause trouble?

Comment: TileParent.cs(12,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You forgot to declare `T` as a [generic type](https://www.dotnetperls.com/generic). Your class should be like `public class TileParent<T> ...`
Then to ensure `T` implements a required type/interface: `public class TileParent<T> where T : UndoClass`. Also make sure to remember to cast as necessary (see: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the generic:

```
public class TileParent<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AddToList<T> _UndoLog = new AddToList<T>();
}
```

Or specificy it:

```
public class TileParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AddToList<TileParent> _UndoLog = new AddToList<TileParent>();
}
```

It is unlikely that either of these are going to be exactly what you want (because Unity controls how MonoBehaviours are created, you won't be able to do the former), but the problem stems from this past here,  where you propagated the generic upwards instead of specifying what type you wanted your list to be:

```
class AddToList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>();
```